# C# webforms onClick event mixing up with form submit

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, code-behind

I have an ordinary form with a post URL and runat server.
Inside this form I have ordinary HTML fields but also a few ASP controls
These ASP Controls are for a captcha I made, however when I press my captcha submit button then it submits the whole form rather than just the onClick code-behind event.
I've tried using LinkButtons and so on rather than ordinary buttons to avoid it confusing the form but it still isn't working.

Is there a way to make a onClick event with postback and everything without posting the form it is inside?

Comment: POSTing a form is part of what a POSTback does.  What behavior did you expect?

Answer (score 0):

That is how ASP.NET works. Code-behind event handlers are executed on the server, so a complete submit-postback-rerender cycle is required to process it.

You can do AJAX-style partial page updates with an UpdateControl. Note that it will still do the entire submit-postback-rerender cycle, but it will only update part of the page.

Comment: So it is literally impossible to have an ordinary form in webforms?

Comment: You can define forms which don't have the runat="server" attribute and you can do any kind of JavaScript magic that inhibits the postback. But to invoke code-behind C# code, you have to do a full postback, partial postback, or as another option, you can call webservices in your ASP.NET application from JS.